# How to create a hidden file in Bash

Tags: bash, hidden-files

What is the bash command to create a hidden file. I want to name it `.httName`.

I have tried googling for this, but none of the forums suggest any work around for this. I am simply looking for the command to solve my issue. If anyone happen to know the answer please help me out.

Comment: Uhm...what have you tried? And how does "touch .httName" not do exactly what you want?

Comment: More apt title might have been: `Creating files in stealth mode`?

Comment: Looks like you are creating the file & not able to `ls` it. :-) Use `ls -A`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create hidden files in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18852292/608639)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files starting with a dot are by default hidden. You can create it simply by

```
touch .httName
```

anyone will still be able to see it using

```
ls -a
```

If you want files to be properly hidden, you will have to change folder permissions using chmod. For example

```
chmod 770 folder_name
```

will prevent users (except the owner and people in the group) from listing the whole directory "folder_name".

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: No, `r` (octal 4) allows listing the filenames in a directory; `x` (octal 1) allows touching (reading, writing, getting attributes, etc) the files *if you know their names*. If you give someone `r--` (e.g. 774) permissions to a directory, they can `ls -a` it, but `ls -l` will fail because it can't get the files' attributes. OTOH if you give someone `--x` (e.g. 771) permissions, they can't list its contents, but can work with files that they know the filenames of.

Answer (score 1):

Any file starting with . in file name is "hidden".

If you've a file and you want to hide it use:

```
mv filename.txt .filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to go further on the hidden point.
As covered after the creation of a hidden type file `.hidden` changes to the permissions of the file and its parent are advised, especially within a multiuser box.

after you : `touch .hidden`
secure the item with: `chmod 600 .hidden`
and secure the parent directory: `chmod go-w ~/parent/`

Answer (score 0):

the file which start with .(dot)filename is always hidden and its used for setting configuration of the application. 
In Linux dot files are used for same purpose.Even you are working in current directory `ls` command should not display hidden file use `la` to shoe hideen directories.