# How to create hidden files in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, hidden-files

In my program, I have to make a file hidden in order to avoid removal or modification of the file.

```
PATH=/etc/
NAME = file
```

Is there a function in C that will allow me to do that?

Comment: prefix the name with a dot

Comment: `create a hidden file in order to avoid remove or modification of file` -- thanks, wasn't aware that hidden files can't be deleted/modified.

Comment: You probably do not want to set the `PATH` variable to `/etc/` in any circumstance.

Comment: Hidden files are simply ignored by the `ls` command (without arguments), and typically are not matched by a glob like `*` but rather require `.*`. Other than that, they enjoy no special protection against removal or modification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just add a `.` to the front of the file name.  Having said that if your goal is to not allow modification of the file change the permissions to something that can't be modified. Something like:

```
chmod 444 fileName
```

Comment: This does not hide a file, nor does it keep anybody from deleting or editing it.

Comment: If you add a `.` in front of the name it definitely does hide the file.  And it definitely doesn't allow it to be edited if you 444 the file.  As for deleting you'd have to change the sticky bit on the directory which is a bit out of scope.

Comment: You're confused on what he means by hidden file.

Comment: So then please enlight me, if the OP does not mean to hide the file to have it kept from modification or deletion.

Comment: Sure let me google that for you, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory

Comment: Dear Grammin: I sure know what a dot-file is. Please see my updated answer on this.

Answer (score 5):

First: others argue with security arguments here. For those: Hidden files have nothing to do with security nor will it prevent somebody from deleting a file if he has propper permission and wants to do that.

*Hidden* means only that tools like `ls`, bash globs or a graphical file managers will not display the files with their default settings. This can be useful to prevent from accidents (see explanation below) or just to keep directory listings more clean. You may try the commands `ls -l $HOME` and `ls -al $HOME` in order to see the differences.

On GNU/Linux systems and UNIXs it is by convention that files which's name begins with a dot `.` will not being displayed by default meaning they are hidden. Like `$HOME/.bashrc`

Solution: Prefix the file name with a dot:

```
.file
```

---

About accidents. Hiding a file can prevent you from accidently removing it when you type something like:

```
rm *
```

The glob above will not list hidden files so they won't get deleted.

Comment: This does not hide a file, nor does it keep anybody from deleting or editing it. `ls -a` shows dot-files.

Comment: @alk hidden files have nothing to do with security. If you are argue so then you are completely wrong in this post

Comment: I do not know from what you conclude I'd link hidden files and security. As far as I understand the question the OP does.

Comment: @alk I just understood that OP wants a hidden file but isn't clear about what *hidden* exactly means. I hope that I've clearified this with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In LINUX Hidden file are start with `.(DOT)`

if you create files with starting `.(DOT)`, those files are hidden.

You can use `chmod`  to set permissions to the file.

if you set only read only then those cannot be modified in program

```
chmod 444 filename
```

if you want to use this from C-language use `system()` function to execute this command

if You use simple  `ls -alF` you can see those files.

the below files are hidden files  In LINUX

```
-rw-------  1 root root   27671 Sep 17 11:40 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    3512 Jul 23 16:30 .bashrc
```

Comment: Sorry, saying `ls -lrt` wouldn't display *hidden* files (i.e. those starting with a `.`).

Comment: This does not hide a file, nor does it keep anybody from deleting or editing it.

Comment: It's `-a` option to `ls` that shows files starting with a `.`.

Comment: yes `-a` is enough, `l` is to show full list with size,permissions and no.of files in the directory  and `F` is to add / for directories...

Answer (score 2):

There are no hidden files on Linux. Some tools don't show files starting with `.` as others already mentioned.

Anyway, you can experiment with putting control characters like new-line into the filename. See [Control characters in filenames are a terrible idea](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html#control):

> Some control characters, particularly the escape (ESC) character, can cause all sorts of display problems, including security problems. Terminals (like xterm, gnome-terminal, the Linux console, etc.) implement control sequences. Most software developers don’t understand that merely displaying filenames can cause security problems if they can contain control characters. The GNU ls program tries to protect users from this effect by default (see the -N option), but many people display filenames without getting filtered by ls — and the problem returns. H. D. Moore’s “Terminal Emulator Security Issues” (2003) summarizes some of the security issues; modern terminal emulators try to disable the most dangerous ones, but they can still cause trouble. A filename with embedded control characters can (when displayed) cause function keys to be renamed, set X atoms, change displays in misleading ways, and so on. To counter this, some programs modify control characters (such as find and ls) — making it even harder to correctly handle files with such names.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are a bit vague: the program creates a file, wants to prevent its removal or modification. Do you expect other users (of your program? in general?) to be able to read it, but not find it easily, or modify or delete it?

Keep in mind that Unix-like systems don't really do hidden when the resource involved needs to remain visible (readable, presumably), as others have noted. Prepending a '.' to a file name helps in some important contexts (default `ls(1)` behavior and shell `*` globbing in particular) but only goes so far. But a few techniques might help obscure what and where your app is saving things, if that matters.

Consider two users doing some shell commands like the following in a directory with its sticky bit set (say /tmp). (Sorry to not write C, but I think the scenario is easier to demonstrate out in the shell.)

As Bob:

```
$ umask 066
$ mkdir /tmp/.hidden
$ umask 022
$ echo xyzzy > /tmp/.hidden/mysecret.txt
$ ls -la /tmp/.hidden
total 28
drwx--x--x  2 bob  users 4096 Sep 17 11:19 .
drwxrwxrwt 27 root root 20480 Sep 17 11:26 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  users    6 Sep 17 11:19 mysecret.txt
```

As Alice. Notice that attempts to search in /tmp/.hidden fail, but if she knows the name of a file in a directory with only execute but not read permissions set, she can read the file. She can't do much to mess with /tmp/.hidden, once it's properly created. If she'd been forced to guess the name of the secret file, that could also be a challenge depending on how the name is created.

```
$ ls /tmp | grep hidden
$ ls -a /tmp | grep hidden
.hidden
$ file /tmp/.hidden
/tmp/.hidden: directory
$ ls /tmp/.hidden 
ls: cannot open directory /tmp/.hidden: Permission denied
$ echo /tmp/.hidden/*
/tmp/.hidden/*
$ file /tmp/.hidden/mysecret.txt
/tmp/.hidden/mysecret.txt: ASCII text
$ cat /tmp/.hidden/mysecret.txt
xyzzy
$ rm -f /tmp/.hidden/mysecret.txt
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/.hidden/mysecret.txt': Permission denied
$ mv /tmp/.hidden /tmp/Hidden_No_More
mv: cannot move '/tmp/.hidden' to '/tmp/Hidden_No_More': Operation not permitted
$ rm -rf /tmp/.hidden 
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/.hidden': Permission denied
```

In this scenario, the presence of the hidden directory can be obscured, but `ls -a` reveals its name. Carefully chosen directory permissions prevent non-root and non-Bob users from listing or altering its contents. The use of a sticky-bit directory like /tmp prevents non-Bobs from renaming or removing the "hidden" directory. Anyone who knows the name of the "secret" file within the hidden directory can read it. But only Bob and root can change these "secret" files or the "hidden" directory.

You can do all the above in a C program; equivalents exist as library and system calls - see things like `chmod(2)`, `mkdtemp(3)`, `umask(2)`, the mode argument to `open(2)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a kernel >= 3.11, you might want to try the `O_TMPFILE`-flag. This kernel have been released on the 14.09.2013. Debian Jessie uses Kernel 3.16. so this feature should be available on all recent popular distributions.

The news about this [sounds promising](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.11#head-8be09d59438b31c2a724547838f234cb33c40357). The file will be unreachable from the outside. No other process or may access this file .. neither read nor write. But the file will be lost as soon as the handle gets closed. Or link it to a regular file. But then, it will be accessible as any other file.

If this is not an option for you (e.g. your file needs to be persistent): bad luck. There is no real "hidden" file in linux. You can hide your persistent files as secure as files on windows with the hidden attribute: prepend the name with a dot. As stated by others: `ls -a` will show them nevertheless.

Also, you can create a user specifically for your use and make the file read- and writable only for this user or put it in a folder, where only your user have rw-access. Other users may see this file but wont be able to access it. But if `root` comes along and want to look into it, you have lost.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,you have to add '.' before filename and your file wouldn't be seen by user(except user will turn the hidden files show option on). You could change the attrybutes (chmod) to 755 and only user could rwx and others could rx.

Answer (score 0):

**hek2mgl** - partially yes - it has. Try to remove via `rm -rf *` manner all of directory content. That's why for example .htaccess is hidden.

Comment: `rm -rf .*`  removes all dot-files.

Comment: I was not talking about if the hidden file can or cannot be removed :) In most cases you are typing only * and hidden file such as conf files are not being removed.